# Replacing a motor under load-torque with 2 motors to give similar performance

Tags: dc-motor, torque

I have the following setup: A servo DC motor which is connected to a drum and the drum drives a conveyor belt. There is a pulley at the other end of the belt which is the same radius as the drum. There is a load placed securely on the belt so that there is no slipping. The load is accelerated or decelerated from rest. But i want to replace the single motor with 2 smaller ones and place each one at the end of the belt with identical servo DC motors, so that the combined performance of the 2 smaller motors are equivalent to the single big motor. So, what differences between the characteristics of the big motor and the two smaller motors should i be looking for?

Here are the characteristics of the big motor:
Tm = time constant
Km = steady-state gain

I'm not sure if i'm missing anything else?

So, my approach to find two smaller motors would be such that each motor would give me half of Tm and half of Km. Am i correct?

Comment: Are you talking about paralleling two motors which will be connected to a single servo controller, or two independent servos (motor/controller/feedback sensor)? Your definitions of 'Tm' and 'Km' seem to imply a complete servo controlled system (which includes the drum and belt etc.). Can you tell us which 'servo DC motor' you have, and what its actual specs are?

Comment: I am thinking of replacing the motor and drum with two motors, at each end of the belt, so there won't be a pulley in the system, but only two drums, each connected to a motor. The setup is only at a modelling stage right now, so i don't have specific hardware at this time but i plan to implement it soon.